# How to pass object ID from Angular.js to Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, angularjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework

Using Django Rest Framework I have defined two serializers:

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ServiceType
        fields = '__all__'

class CompanyShortListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    services = ServiceSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ( 'id','name', 'address', 'cost_per_patient', 'cost_per_month', 'renting_fee', 'services')
```

Where the ServiceType model consists of three fields:

```
class ServiceType(models.Model):
     serviceName = EncryptedCharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
     servicePrice = EncryptedFloatField(null=True, blank=True)
     company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name = 'services')
```

No need to mention the Company model since it's not important here.

Using Angular I would like to update companies by e.g. removing a given service from a defined Company.

The data in my $http.PUT related to services looks like this:

```
services:Array[3]
    0:Object
        $$hashKey:"object:26"
        company:49
        id:67
        serviceName:"Terapia"
        servicePrice:100
        __proto__:Object
   *ommitting the others for brevity*
```

etc.

Please **note that the id is sent in this object**. However when I try to do this:

```
 def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    # Updates and exisitng Company with several services 
    instance.name = validated_data['name']
    instance.address = validated_data['address']
    instance.cost_per_patient = validated_data['cost_per_patient']
    instance.renting_fee = validated_data['renting_fee']

    # create or update page instances that are in the request
    for service in validated_data['services']:
        updatedService = ServiceType(id=service['id'], serviceName = service['serviceName'], servicePrice = service['servicePrice'], company=instance)
        updatedService.save()

    return instance
```

The line **`id=service['id']` creates an error since `service` does not contain the id field**. What this function receives is on Ordered Dictionary like this:

```
[ 
OrderedDict([(u'serviceName', u'Terapia'), (u'servicePrice', 100.0), (u'company ', <Company: Test 1>)]), 
OrderedDict([(u'serviceName', u'Terapia par'), (u'servicePrice', 150.0), (u'company', <Company: Test 1>)]), 
OrderedDict([(u'serviceName ', u'Terapia po angielsku'), (u'servicePrice', 120.0), (u'company', <Company: Test 1>)])
]
```

What is wrong - why is the ID not passed to the serializer and how to fix that? 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully analyzing this point I started a new question about the serializer and id field which can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473795/django-rest-framework-model-id-field-in-nested-relationship-serializer/36501622#36501622) which I basically managed to eventually solve :) Ufff!