# Deserialize POST request with subset of serializer fields in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I'm having a rather simple problem, but found a few solutions and couldn't stop wondering what the intended DRF approach would be.

I have a (simplified) model and serializer like this:

```
class CartProduct(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class CartProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    product = ProductSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = CartProduct
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'product')
```

Which produces a GET response like this:

```
"url": "http://localhost:8000/appUsers/1/cart/products/16/",
"id": 16,
"product": {
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/products/1/",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Tomatoes",
},
"cart": "http://localhost:8000/carts/1/"
```

However, when creating a new CartProduct now, in this default scenario I would need to pass a nested product dictionary like the one above to create / deserialize a new CartProduct from a POST request.

What I would like instead is to send a POST request with a body using just primary keys or urls to create a new cart product, e.g. like this:

```
"product": 1,
"cart": 1
```

or

```
"product": "http://localhost:8000/products/1/"
"cart": "http://localhost:8000/carts/1/"
```

So now I was wondering what would be the best way to achieve this? I thought of:

- Writing two separate serializers (but I don't like the idea of having two serializers for pretty much every model like this)
- Adding additional fields to every serializer making sure that nested / related models are always represented by url and / or id and only making these ID fields required
- Overriding the validation / create function in order to make the desired input a valid format
- Overriding the ModelViewSet's create functions and dealing with the issue there

What would be the most appropriate place for dealing with such a case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use the following approach where I have **2 serializer fields for 1 model field** (one read only field for details and one id/url field for creates and updates):

```
class CartProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    product_detail = ProductSerializer(source='product', read_only=True) 

    class Meta:
        model = CartProduct
        fields = ('url', 'cart', 'product', 'product_detail')
```

Note that this assumes `ProductSerializer` is already defined elsewhere. And I'm omitting id because we don't really need it but you can still add it if you want.

This has the following advantages:

- You can use the same serializer for all CRUD operations.
- You get the nested field details on GET but can just provide ids for those nested fields on POST / PUT.
- You don't have to write any custom logic in your views to parse etc. - you can stick with the default generic view functionality that you get out of the box

So in your specific case, the JSON you'll get back for a GET will be:

```
{
  "url": "http://localhost:8000/appUsers/1/cart/products/16/",
  "product": "http://localhost:8000/products/1/"
  "product_detail": {
    "url": "http://localhost:8000/products/1/",
    "name": "Tomatoes",
  },
  "cart": "http://localhost:8000/carts/1/"
}
```

And for POSTs you'll only need to send:

```
{
  "product": "http://localhost:8000/products/2/"
  "cart": "http://localhost:8000/carts/1/"
}
```

For PUTs, include the `CartProduct` object's own `url` in the above JSON.

Comment: This is great, but what if the input is not an ID but some other value of the related entity. In this example, say its the product_name? so the POST body would look like:
`{ "product": "Tomatoes", "cart": 1 }`

Answer (score 1):

So you want the deserialized `CartProductSerializer` to include a nested representation of `Product`, while on the other hand, when serializing, you wish to provide only an id of an existing `Product`? You're right that creating an additional field is one solution, and I like it best.

1. Set `product` as read-only, since you do not actually accept a nested `product` dictionary in your serializer ([you can, though](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)).
2. Create a new field, `product_id = ModelField(model_field=Product()._meta.get_field('id'))`. This will allow you to pass `product_id` when serializing. If you want to exclude this when deserializing, you can set it as write-only. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36501622/410963).

Comment: I like that, didn't know that read-only=True solves this issue. Why would you chose a ModelField instead of a PrimaryKeyRelatedField for step 2?

Comment: That might work. What happens if you use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`?

Answer (score 1):

You can change serializer behaviour by overriding `to_representation` method

```
class CartProduct(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class CartProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = CartProduct
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'product')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        self.fields['product'] = ProductSerializer(read_only=True)
        return super().to_representation(instance)
```

This way your serializer will use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` by default and on showing representation it will use nested `ProductSerializer`

**NOTE:** also you don't need to explicitly supply `id` field if it is default `AutoField`, just adding it in `fields` meta option should be enough