# Related model ID gets lost in validated_data even though it is present in request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am working on my create() method for my webapp which uses Django REST framework for the backend API.

In this case, I'm trying to create a new RECIPE, which has a foreignkey field to a related model STYLE...

I am running into an issue when trying to associate my new recipe record with an existing related object via the ID.

My serializers looks like this:

```
class StyleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    class Meta:
        model = Style
        exclude = ()

class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hops = HopAdditionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    fermentables = FermentableAdditionSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    style = StyleSerializer()
    yeast = YeastSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        exclude = ()
    def create(self, validated_data):
        style_data = validated_data.pop('style')
        style = Style.objects.get(pk=style_data.get('id'))
        reipce = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)
        recipe.style = style
        recipe.save();
        return recipe
```

You can see I'm trying to assign the new recipe object with a related Style object.

On my POST request for a new recipe, I include the style, which is all of the related attributes including the field **ID**. I have verified this info is getting POSTED both in the request via dev console AND in the django viewset via terminal log.

However, in my serializer create() method, the ID value is always missing from the dictionary object returned by validated_data.pop('style'). Every other field is present, just the ID that is missing.

I can get the style object using the name attribute, but I don't understand why the ID of the related Style object gets lost in the validated_data, even though it is present in the POST.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I found the answer...

I needed to include this line in the StyleSerializer to explicity include the ID in the validated_data:

```
id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
```

Full Serializer

```
class StyleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Style
        exclude = ()
```

[Related StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473795/django-rest-framework-model-id-field-in-nested-relationship-serializer)

Answer (score -1):

```
   def create(self, instance, validated_data):
        style_data = validated_data.pop('style')
        style = (instance.style).all()
        style = list(style)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).