# Django - AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

The api call somehow ignores the id that has been sent with the container object.
It gives me a null for the id of both container.

When I try to check for the id in any way for example `print(container.get("id")`, it gives me that attribute error. What could I be doing wrong?

Here is the serializer:

```
class GoodsInSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    containers = ContainerSerializer(required=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = GoodsIn
        fields = (
            'id', 'name', 'warehouse', 'containers', )
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        goodsin_obj = GoodsIn.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        warehouse = validated_data.get('warehouse')

        containers = None
        if 'containers' in validated_data:
            containers = validated_data.pop('containers')

        if containers:
            print(containers)
            keep_container = []
            container_list = [
                container for container in Container.objects.filter(goods_in=goodsin_obj)]
            for container in containers:
                # the id does not reach the ordered dictionary
                if container.get('id'):
                    container_obj = Container.objects.get(
                        id=container.get('id'))
                else:
                    container_obj = Container.objects.create(**container)
                    container_obj.checked_in = False
                    container_obj.warehouse_id = warehouse
                    container_obj.goods_in = goodsin_obj
                    container_obj.save()
                keep_container.append(container_obj)

            for container in container_list:
                if container not in keep_container:
                    container.delete()
```

This is the data that I am sending to the api call:

```
{
    "warehouse":"warehouse1",
    "containers":[{
    "id":"332131",
    "product": "pencil",
    "quantity": 33,
    "grade": "Grade B",
    "checked_in": true
},{
    "id":"122331",
    "product": "xyz",
    "quantity": 101,
    "grade": "Grade B",
    "checked_in": false
}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This resolved it:

[Related model ID gets lost in validated_data even though it is present in request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661333/related-model-id-gets-lost-in-validated-data-even-though-it-is-present-in-reques)

I needed to add to my `ContainerSerializer` the following:

```
id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
```

Someone might come along and show me a better method so I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you've set the `id` as a read-only field on your serializer. The `Meta` class of your serializer should look like this:

```py
class GoodsInSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    containers = ContainerSerializer(required=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = GoodsIn
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'warehouse', 'containers', )
   
   # your update method here
```

Comment: I applied that and its the same results, I removed it as read only from the 'ContainerSerializer' as well.